# Prolog "filter" a list

Tags: list, filter, prolog

I am trying to solve an exercise for my school in which I am asked to make a function called *filter(+Lin,+Min,+Max,-Lout)* which is supposed to modify Lin(List) so that Lout(List) only has the numbers within the limits set by Min and Max.

```
ex. ?- filter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],3,6,L).
L = [3, 4, 5, 6].
```

I tried lot of things, I also searched here for answers but there is something in the logic of Prolog that I can't quite get..

What I have done so far.I am using chop function to append the Head to a list each time if the head is inside the limits.

```
chop([H|T],H,T).

filter([],MIN,MAX,[]).
filter([H|T],MIN,MAX,LOUT):-(H>MIN,H<MAX),
    chop(LOUT,H,LIST),filter(T,MIN,MAX,LOUT).
filter([H|T],MIN,MAX,LOUT):-(H<MIN;H>MAX),
    filter(T,MIN,MAX,LOUT).
```

If you can answer my question and you don't mind a bit of explaining I will really appreciate it!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't see a question. What is it? You want `H > MIN` *AND* `H < MAX` don't you? The `;` logically is *OR*. And you have the case for `H` being between `MIN` and `MAX` but you left out the rule for if it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right about the _AND_ . However my code doesn't work and I really can't figure out whats wrong..How am I supposed to append the Head to a list each time if its within the limits and then print the list?

Comment: Like I said, you're missing a clause which expresses the case when `H` is not between `MIN` and `MAX`. Currently, as soon as it hits such a case, your predicate will fail and produce no results.

Comment: I understand what you are saying however with my limited experience with prolog I can't figure it out. Is it possible fix my code? Thank you

Comment: Yes it's possible to fix. Like I said, you are just missing one more rule which is a lot like the one you have already. You have two rules (clauses) currently, one that says what a filtered empty list looks like, and one that says what a filtered list with a head that is inside the range looks like. You now just need one that says what a filter list with a head that is outside the range looks like.

Comment: I edited the code a bit using your advice, now I have a rule when the head is out of range. Also am I using the chop function correctly to append the Head each time to a new list so I can print it at the end?

Comment: Your second clause (for `H` in range) isn't correct. Look at it carefully. You're discarding the tail of the list after the `chop` rather than using it.

Answer (score 1):

First you must create a rule that handles empty lists:

```
filter([], _, _, []).
```

Then a rule to handle elements between `Min` and `Max`:

```
filter([X|Lin], Min, Max, [X|Lout]) :- X >= Min,
                                       X =< Max, !,
                                       filter(Lin, Min, Max, Lout).
```

Finally you need a rule that ignores elements out of bounds:

```
filter([_|Lin], Min, Max, Lout) :- filter(Lin, Min, Max, Lout).
```

That’s all!

Comment: You can avoid using a cut in two ways: make the opposite check in the other clause, or use the `->` control predicate.

Comment: Yes, that’s a way. But in this case, I need to use `;`, or create two other rules. So, I prefer to use the cut. And the first cut was not necessary, so I remove it.

Comment: If you used `Cond -> then ; else` then you achieve exactly the same as your current solution, **but** you avoid creating and discarding a choice point. Take a look at the [implementation of `include/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/apply.pl?show=src#include/3).

Comment: Thank you for the answer I understand now!

Comment: Yes, that’s an approach. You made me curious: what’s the practical difference between using `-> ;` approach and multiple choice points? How it can affect the performance?

Comment: @Arĥimedeςℳontegasppα (I don't see your comments in my inbox unless you address them to me.) You definitely need to measure this for the implementation you are using. With SWI-Prolog, creating a choice point and discarding it with a cut is always slower than using the `(Cond -> Then ; Else)` construct with identical semantics. This is why library predicates in SWI-Prolog use that instead of a cut, especially when it needs to happen on each iteration. You will see cuts when they are not in performance-critical spots and make the code cleaner.

Comment: @Boris Thanks for the explanation! That’s exactly my doubt. When I’m programming in Prolog, I usually use SWI-Prolog. I used to prefer cut because of clearness/cleanness, but now I will think more about perfomance in those cases.

Comment: @Arĥimedeςℳontegasppα The cut is definitely **not** "cleaner", either: it is sometimes easier to overlook while reading the code, and it is not always obvious what solutions you are skipping because of it. And some of the classical use of the cut: failure-driven loops, or code as your solution above -- can be replaced with control predicates or library predicates. The cut is still useful of course, just not as often.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a question in your question, so some advice and comments instead.

The straight-forward way to do this would be to use two library predicates, [`between/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3) and [`include/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3). BTW, `include/3` and `exclude/3` from [`library(apply)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply) are (SWI-)Prolog's `filter`.

```
?- include(between(3, 6), [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], Out).
Out = [3, 4, 5, 6].
```

As for your own solution: it is almost there, but it has some strange stuff going on. You don't need your `chop/3` at all, as far as I can see.
There are also some unnecessary parentheses. The second clause looks more familiar if you write it as:

```
filter([X|Xs], Min, Max, [X|Ys]) :-
    X >= Min,
    X =< Max,
    filter(Xs, Min, Max, Ys).
```

Note that this also doesn't have the off-by-one error at the limits of the Min-Max range.

The last clause, on the other hand, has something which you meant to use as a logical OR, but this: `( X < Min ; X > Max )` is not exactly what you think it is. Look:

```
?- ( 1 < 3 ; 1 > 6).
true ;
false.
```

This is both true, *and* it is false. Rather:

```
?- \+ ( 1 >= 3, 1 =< 6 ).
true.
```

or even better:

```
?- \+ between(3, 6, 1).
true.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it all seems clearer now!

Comment: What you are saying about `( 1 < 3 ; 1 > 6 )` being "both true [...] and false" is wrong, and worse, very misleading!